# How can I create this custom view in Android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, dynamic-view

I have to add an ordered list of items as following images. How can I achieve that in Android?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make drawables for each of the  dot and line. And then make your custom View extending ImageView and override the onCanvas() where you can simply draw these drawables on the basis of whatever criteria you have.
To adjust the spacing in between just get the ImageView height and width and space according to that.